# Should I use if-else in using whereIn()

Tags: php, laravel

`$search_val` is array when it has two or more values. But when `$search_val` has only one value, `$search_val` is not array. It will be number.

In this case, should I use if-else?

*case1: not use if-else*

```
$query->whereIn('column', $search_val);
```

*case2: if-else*

```
if (is_array($search_val)) {
  $query->whereIn('column', $search_val);
} else {
  $query->where('column', $search_val);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question has some interesting aspects that need to be answered in order to form a proper answer.

**Can `whereIn` function take a scalar (i.e. non-array) value?**

From [Laravel's code here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L823), it doesn't handle scalar values. So this means we have to supply an array - and therefore means that your *Case 1* above will not work.

**Can `if`/`else` statements be used to determine where to use `whereIn` or `where`?**

Of course! But eventually the length of your function (in terms of number of lines) grows when the actual usefulness of the function doesn't increase one bit.

You could do it in one line:

```
$query->whereIn('column', is_array($search_val) ? $search_val : [$search_val]);
```

Which makes things slightly neater. But my guess is that eventually you might end up (perhaps elsewhere) with such checks more often than you'd like. In fact, that could be considered a [code smell](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells).

**Fix the source of the problem**

My suggestion would be to fix the source of the problem - the function or piece of code that returns either an array or a scalar value. Make it always return an array. If it's only a single value, make it convert that into a one-element array.

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
$query->whereIn('column', is_array($search_val) ? $search_val : [$search_val]);
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.